# Convert JavaScript piece of code to python

Tags: javascript, python, reduce

I'm trying to convert a JavaScript module to Python. And I do not know much about JavaScript. Below is the js line which is confusing for me.

```
for(i=0; i<res.response.length;i++)
    for (var key in temp['sal_changes'][0]['sal_by_per'])
        {
           res.response[i]['sal_changes'][0]['sal_by_per'][key.replace(' ','_')]=(res.response[i]['sal_changes'][0]['sal_by_per'][key].toFixed(2))/1;
           change.push(temp['sal_changes'][0]['sal_by_per'][key])
        }
        totalchange=change.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
    }
```

Also I'm using python 2.7 reduce function is not available.

I want python code for these two lines of js code:

```
res.response[i]['sal_changes'][0]['sal_by_per'][key.replace(' ','_')]=(res.response[i]['sal_changes'][0]['sal_by_per'][key].toFixed(2))/1;
```

and

```
totalchange=change.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
```

Comment: Python 2.7 has reduce function. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: This `reduce` can replaced by `sum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, `temp` and `res.response[i]` are the same object, leading to

```
sal_by_per = temp['sal_changes'][0]['sal_by_per']
totalchange = sum(sal_by_per.values())
```

Comment: temp and res.response[i] are same only if condition is met